# VSCode - How to disable highlight color for open files on file explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since Version 1.26.1 (1.26.1), The File Explorer is highlighting the open files and the directories with a green color. I find this really distracting since it's overwriting the colors from git lense (yellow for changes/new files) and eslint (red for errors).

Is there a way to disable that?

See example:
[image]

Comment: You could try the setting `"explorer.decorations.colors": false`

Comment: Are you sure those are opened files and not modified files?  If modified, try     // "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#fff",

Comment: no, the modified are more yellowish, the fact that they both really similar is what bothered me the most.

Comment: @DanielRavina have you found an answer? Accepted one just disables all highlighting including git lense so not an option. Really annoying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Preferences:

`explorer.decorations.colors`

Controls whether file decorations should use colors.

```
"explorer.decorations.colors": true,//shows colors

"explorer.decorations.colors": false, //displays no colors
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this is also disabling eslint and git lense altogether. Is there a way to make it specific only for "open files" ?

Comment: Try the "sideBar.foreground" "#ffffff" ( white color ) in the settings file.

Comment: Weird. it seems like the green color is only happening on one project. I didn't see any specific config code there. I don't really know how to explain it. I'll accept the answer regardless.